# debugging a uwsgi python application using pycharm

Tags: debugging, pycharm, uwsgi

Is it possible to debug a uwsgi application using an ide like PyCharm? I can debug flask based apps fine by running them directly from pycharm but cannot even run a uwsgi app from within pycharm.

Do I have to use remote debugging? Is it possible to start a uwsgi app from within pycharm using run?

Comment: If your wsgi app starts from a Python scripts its very possible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can still run your WSGI app outside of uWSGI for development and debugging purposes.

However sometimes this is not possible, for example if your app relies on uWSGI API features.

As far as I know you can't use "Attach to Process" from PyCharm because your WSGI app is running embedded into uWSGI, and there are no visible Python processes. [Remote debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/remote-debugging.html) however works like a charm.

1. Locate `pycharm-debug*.egg` files in your PyCharm distribution. For example, on OSX both can be found in `/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents`
2. Copy `pycharm-debug-py3k.egg` next to your Flask app, or copy `pycharm-debug.egg` instead if you are using Python 2.7
3. In PyCharm, create a "Python Remote Debug" configuration from "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog. In this example I use `localhost` and port `4444`. This dialog will show you the corresponding `pydevd.settrace(...)` line.
4. Add the following code to your app :

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.append('pycharm-debug-py3k.egg')  # replace by pycharm-debug.egg for Python 2.7
   import pydevd
   # the following line can be copied from "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog
   pydevd.settrace('localhost', port=4444, stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
   ```
5. In PyCharm, start the remote debugging session. PyCharm's console should display the following line :

   ```
   Waiting for process connection...
   ```
6. Run your app from uWSGI as usual. It should attach to the debugger, and PyCharm's console should display :

   ```
   Connected to pydev debugger (build 139.711)
   ```
7. Your app should break on the `pydevd.settrace(...)` line. You can then continue and use PyCharm debugger as usual (breakpoints and so on)

Comment: How does this approach change if you have the same uwsgi setup except now you have docker-compose file with a few services?

Comment: @rexbelia did you ever figure it out with docker compose? My uswgi process won't fork for some reason

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to interpret your question, as you are mixing apples and oranges. Flask is a framework, uWSGI is an application server. I'll try to answer, though.

As far as I know, uWSGI is not pure python, so debugging it in PyCharm will not be trivial, if even it is possible.

However, since you are using uWSGI to run your application, I'm assuming it complies with the [WSGI protocol](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). In that case, for debugging purposes, you can alternatively run it from a simple pure-python application engine like [wsgiref.simple_server.WSGIServer](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/wsgiref.html?highlight=wsgiref#module-wsgiref.simple_server).

Comment: Running with builtin WSGIServer is a great idea indeed. Also available in [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html#module-wsgiref.simple_server). I did this to debug a *hug* application by referencing `__hug_wsgi__` as the wsgi handler ([more info](https://github.com/timothycrosley/hug#running-hug-with-other-wsgi-based-servers)).

Answer (score 2):

There is now an official guide on how to do this:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#

If your code already exists in remote, you only need to follow `Create a run/debug configuration﻿`

You'll need the IP where the PyCharm is running. When you run the remote debugger from PyCharm, it'll create a debugging server. Your code will connect to this server.

In my case, I'm using Vagrant, with private IP of the guest 192.168.0.3, and the host's private IP is 192.168.0.1.
My code in the remote guests will connect to the debugging server through the host IP. So I need to use my host IP in the code that I want to debug.