# How to debug python script with pyCharm when the script is not started by python?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, uwsgi

I have a local pylons app that I've been developing and debugging with pyCharm. We have been using "paster", which is a python script,  to serve out this website. In my debugging configuration I specify "paster" as the script to launch, and feed it the parameters it needs to launch my website. I can then set breakpoints in my website code and when they are hit, I can debug.

That all works great.

Recently though, our company is switching to uwsgi, instead of paster. So to run my website, I will now be launching uwsgi instead of paster. The problem I'm running in to is that uwsgi is not a python script. When I specify the uwsgi (a binary executable) as the script to start in my debugging configuration, pyCharm complains.

So my broader question is: Is there a way to use pyCharm to debug a python script when that script is not launched by something that's python based?

I posed this question to JetBrains and theire support was not that great, it was like "Try remote debugging". But honestly, I don't see how remote debugging well help. Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks so much
Michael

Comment: try: Tools → Attach to process. Dunno if this will work. Edit: lol, asked 9 months ago

Comment: Answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21257568/debugging-a-uwsgi-python-application-using-pycharm?rq=1